# i want to call page on button click but following error occurs

Tags: angular

```
ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Provided Component class doesn't contain Component definition. Please check whether provided class has @Component decorator. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]
at throwError2 (core.mjs:392:11)
at assertDefined (core.mjs:388:9)
at ViewContainerRef2.createComponent (core.mjs:19969:17)
at _RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.mjs:2423:31)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3033:28)
at router.mjs:2987:12
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.mjs:2986:25)
at ActivateRoutes.activate (router.mjs:2897:10)
at router.mjs:2881:120
handleError @ core.mjs:11760
```

Angular Version: 17

update-data.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UpdateDataService } from '../Services/update-data.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-update-data',
standalone: true,
imports: [RouterLink, HttpClientModule, CommonModule],
templateUrl: './update-data.component.html',
styleUrl: './update-data.component.css'
})
export class UpdateDataComponent {
constructor(private objUpdate: UpdateDataService) { }

 };
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { GetDataService } from './Services/get-data.service';
import { UpdateDataService } from './Services/update-data.service';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root', 
  standalone: true, 
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink], 
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrl: './app.component.css' 
}) export class AppComponent { 
    title = 'Angular Crud With WebApi'; 
    constructor(private obj: GetDataService, private objUpdate: UpdateDataService){}
 };
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UpdateData } from './Model/update-data';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path: "Home", component: HomeComponent },
{path: "UpdateData", component:UpdateData },
 ];
```

i am trying to call page, but it gives me error message.

```
i am trying to call page on button click but it gives error.
```

Comment: It seems you have confused `UpdateData` vs `UpdateDataComponent`

Comment: @DucHo could you add an answer?

Comment: @ronin-hawkeye If your problem is still not resolved then could you please provide the source? You can use something such as [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In standalone, if you want to use routes, you need add as provider in your app.component (the component that have the `<router-outlet>`)

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
});
```